# RSpec—testing if cookie was created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I can manually check and see that it works, but I want an rspec test that will show my `create` method adds a cookie as well as creating my record. With my current code, no cookies are found... any ideas?

My test:

```
describe "POST create" do
  subject { post :create, table: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:table) }
  it "creates table" do
    expect { subject }.to change(Table, :count).by(1)
  end
  it "bakes cookies" do
    expect(response.cookies["my_cookie"].to exist)
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
def create
    @table = Table.new(table_params)
    if @table.save
      bake_cookie @table.id
      redirect_to show_table_path, notice: "Table created."
    else
    ...
end

def bake_cookie table_id
  cookies["my_cookie"] = { value: table_id, expires: 12.hours.from_now }
end
```

Comment: Is that typo in `bakes cookies` it assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
it "bakes cookies" do
  subject
  expect(!!response.cookies["my_cookie"]).to eq true
end
```

The original code didn't have `subject`, so the `create` method was never actually run. It also used `exist` which is deprecated.